# Why only in Dhul'hijjah can the Hajj be done, what is the reason?

Tags: ramadan, hajj

What happens if somebody wants to do this out of the <strike>Ramadan</strike>Dhul'hijjah?

*Extension:* Sorry, I knew it badly! I didn't know it should be done on Dhul'hijjah.

Comment: @MorningStar just as an addition to the other comments there are ahadith saying that a 'Omra (a smaller pilgrimage) during Ramadan is like a Hajj (awards not value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hajj is not to be done in Ramadan. it is to be done in Dhu al-Hijjah ( ذو الحجة) but i get your question :)

we don't do Hajj on any other month because that what our prophet told us, and also in the Quran: god said

Quran2:197
"**Hajj is [during] well-known months**, so whoever has made Hajj obligatory upon himself therein [by entering the state of ihram], there is [to be for him] no sexual relations and no disobedience and no disputing during Hajj. And whatever good you do - Allah knows it. And take provisions, but indeed, the best provision is fear of Allah . And fear Me, O you of understanding."

If you want to read more about Hajj you can go to this Wiki page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hajj

Peace brother ;)

Comment: Seems like the Quran is saying Hajj can be done in other "months" as you quoted...

Comment: @Sayyid well 'arafa is 9th dhil Hijja, and the days of tashriq are starting on 10th dhil Hijja, so you can't complete hajj before this. But the Verse refer to the niyya and to when one can start wearing ihram for Hajj!